# Why does ethereum chaindata sometimes sync while syncing?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, fast-sync, chaindata

I am doing a fresh geth 1.9.18-stable sync, which I believe is `fast` by default. I am keeping an eye on the size of the `.ethereum/geth/chaindata/` directory and have noticed that it does not increase monotonically. Sometimes the size goes down.

Why?